# zombienet vs parachain-launch

Tags: zombienet, polkadot-launch, parachain-launch

I was looking at setting up a nice testing workflow and was wondering if anyone could recommend one over the other ([zombienet](https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet) vs [parachain-launch](https://github.com/open-web3-stack/parachain-launch)). Note that [polkadot-launch](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-launch) is deprecated.

They seem quite similar from a beginners point of view so it would be nice to hear from someone with some insight

Felix

Answer (score 2):

As you said for beginners point of view the are very similar, so is up to you which with one you feel more comfortable and which one is easier for you.

You can read [this discussion on the Polkadot forum](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/chopsticks-substrate-testing-client/878/9) where there is a comparation of both.

For me personally I use Zombienet but simply because I found better documentation: [zombienet](https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/blob/main/README.md), [Zombienet Walkthrough | Sub0 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKTZZCpdGH4) and [Simulate parachains in a test network](https://docs.substrate.io/test/simulate-parachains/) and more examples about how to use it like [zombienet repo](https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/tree/main/examples) and [trappist](https://github.com/paritytech/trappist).

Comment: thanks for the info Alex! Youre the man.